# React Typeahead Test Not Calling API

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to write a test for my react bootstrap typeahead. On keyboard value enter, a HTTP .GET request should be made. In my test, when i enter values, my `spy` is never called.

Typeahead:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import { AsyncTypeahead } from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead'; // ES2015
import 'react-bootstrap-typeahead/css/Typeahead.css';
import axios from 'axios';

export const Description = () => {
  const [tyOptions, setOpts] = useState([]);

  const handleSearch = (id) => {
    axios
      .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)
      .then(({ options }) => {
        console.log(options);
        setOpts(options);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <AsyncTypeahead
        id="test"
        labelKey="title"
        minLength={1}
        onSearch={handleSearch}
        options={tyOptions}
        placeholder="Search todo by id."
        renderMenuItemChildren={(option) => (
          <>
            <span>
              Test
            </span>
          </>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Test:

```
describe("App Component Testing", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    it('should get typeahead data', async () => {
        let axios = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(
            {
                data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            }
        ));

        let component;

        await act(async () => {
            component = render(<Description/>);
        });

        let inputEl = component.queryByPlaceholderText(/Search todo by id./);

        userEvent.click(inputEl);
        userEvent.type(inputEl, 'test val');

        expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Error:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled();
Expected number of calls: => 1
Received number of calls: 0
```

Comment: What version of `userEvent` are you using? Methods since v14 return promises and need to be `await`ed. The `onSearch` handler is also async, so you may need to `await` the results there before asserting.

Comment: Upgrade as per above, and worked. Thank you.